# Launch IOS Mobile App from web browser using MVC

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc-4

I have my Apps installed in my device. Now I want to launch the apps from email hyperlink click

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom URL scheme so that apps can send information to your app using URLs.

Read the [Inter-App Communication Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html). You are looking for URL schemes.

Comment: Custom URL defined and I can call like 'MyApp://' while I am sending this URL details to safari browser it is not opening the app where as if I type 'MyApp://' in safari browser it is working.

Comment: @Sukanta please clarify. I don't understand your comment.